# Sharepoint List randomly duplicating submitted Item

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath

I have some weird problem that I encounter while working with Sharepoint custom list. Sometimes created list is duplicating itself. But the workflows of the duplicated item is not running. Anyone having this same issue?[image]

Comment: Are you duplicating newly created items in your workflow?

Comment: hi i dont have any duplicate workflow here. its randomly duplicating

Answer (score 0):

With the maximum likelihood of duplication in the workflow (Create Item List), in one of the conditions, check the flags in each step, or log in and check.